# What is the maximum number of troops that can be on the field at once?

Tags: mount-and-blade-warband

Without any modifications to the game, what is the maximum number of troops that one side can have on the battlefield at any given time?

Are both the attackers and defenders allocated the same number of troops? (Provided they have enough reserves to fill the slots.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The maximum amount of troops on the battlefield is determined by a setting in the options menu, with a maximum of 150 total. the ratio of troops on either side is determined by the total amount in both armies and the relative tactics stat of both.

For instance, with 200 solders, fighting a group of 100, with even tactics scores you would get 100 men on the battlefield and they would get 50. fighting a thousand, you would get 30 or so to their 120. Once the ratio has been changed, (by death) then each side gets reinforcements at gradually slowing intervals until the unused fighters are used up. If an army is entirely defeated before the reinforcements arrive again, another battle is fought, until one  of the armies is exhausted.

Comment: If you go into the game files you can set it to like any number you want. It's not that well optimized though so it runs like shit with anything past like 250-300 area even on a really good PC.

Answer (score -2):

I think it is 150 your troops and 150 enemy troops.

And yes.

Comment: any references?

Comment: Can you provide any sources or screenshots? I have been unable to produce more than 150 total troops (both sides combined) on the field at any given time with the default settings. This leads me to believe that you cannot have more than 150 total combined troops from both sides, not each side.

Comment: This is incorrect.  Its 150 total.